# How to add a list of Steps to Job in spring batch

Tags: spring-batch

I'm extending existing `Job`. What I need to do is update a list of records from database with data gotten from external service. I don't know how to do it in a loop so I thought about creating a list of `Steps` each consisting of `reader`, `processor` and `writer` and simply adding them to `next()` method in a jobBuilder. Looking at documentation it's only possible to add one `Step` at a time, and I have several thousands rows in the database, thus several thousands `Steps`. How should I do this?

edit:

in short I need to:

1. read a list of ids from db,
2. for every id I need to call external service to get information relevant to this id,
3. process data from it
4. save updated row to db

Comment: Can you elaborate on your use case?

Comment: If you are trying to:
1. read database records
2. fetch data from a webservice 
3. process data 
4. write to database 
Here is a similar use case I have done before https://github.com/awadodeh/log-batch